# Find the value of $\int_{0}^{1} (mx+b) dx$ using Darboux sums based on regular partitions of the interval $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus

Calculuate $\int_{0}^{1} mx+b\  dx$ by calculating the upper and lower Darboux sums based on the regular partitions of the interval $[0,1]$ and then using the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem.

Clearly the answer is $b+\frac{1}{2}m$ and I think the regular partitions is $\frac{1}{n}$. I am messing up calculating the darboux sums. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be the map $x\mapsto mx+b$ and $$\mathcal P_n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \left\{\frac in\right\}, n\in\mathbb N$$ be a sequence of partitions of $[0,1]$. Assume without loss of generality that $m>0$ (else consider the integral of $-f$). Then the upper and lower Darboux sums of $\mathcal P_n$ are
$$U_f(\mathcal P_n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1n\left( m\left(\frac{i+1}n\right)+b\right) $$
and
$$L_f(\mathcal P_n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1n\left( m\left(\frac{i}n\right)+b\right).$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
U_f(\mathcal P_n)-L_f(\mathcal P_n)&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1n\left(m\left(\frac{i+1}n -\frac in\right) \right)\\
&=\frac mn\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac1n\\
&= \frac mn\left( n\cdot\frac1n\right)\\
&= \frac mn\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0.
\end{align}
From the Archimedes-Riemann theorem we conclude that $\int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathsf dx$ exists and
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathsf dx &= \lim_{n\to\infty} U_f(\mathcal P_n)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1n\left( m\left(\frac{i+1}n\right)+b\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac m{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i + \frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{mn(n+1)}{2n^2} + b \right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac12 m\left(\frac{n+1}n\right) + b\right)\\
&= \frac12 m + b.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Starting at $i = 0$, the $i^{th}$ section of the $n^{th}$ regular partition goes from $\frac{i}{n}$ to $\frac{i+1}{n}$. The function $mx+b$ is increasing, so its minimum on a closed interval occurs at the least element. Thus,
$$L(mx+b, P_n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}(m\frac{i}{n}+b) = b + \frac{m}{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i = b+\frac{m}{n^2}\frac{n^2-n}{2} = b+\frac{m(n-1)}{2n}$$
Which converges to $b+\frac{m}{2}$. Similarly, 
$$U(mx+b, P_n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}(m\frac{i+1}{n}+b) = b + \frac{m}{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1) = b+\frac{m}{n^2}\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$ 
$$= b+\frac{m(n+1)}{2n}$$
Which also converges to $b+\frac{m}{2}$, and so the Darboux integral exists and equals $b+\frac{m}{2}$.